# Pandas: Select last dates from cut-off level

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, grouping

I have a list of dates and a cut-off level: 31st of March. I want to look at the first date before 31st of March and make that the last date in the year and then select the last 3 before and put them into 1 year. (E.g: If we look at 1997, the first date before March 1997, is: index 8, date: 1996-12-13. Now I want to look back 3 dates and put them under the same year, 1997, meaning index 7,6 and 5 | The same with 1995, the first date before March 1995, is index 0, date: 1994-12-15, but there is no available data before index 0).

My data look like this:

```
    date
0   1994-12-15
1   1995-07-06
2   1995-09-13
3   1995-12-12
4   1996-03-14
5   1996-07-01
6   1996-09-17
7   1996-11-12
8   1996-12-13
9   1997-06-25
10  1997-09-10
11  1997-12-12
```

And I want it to look in the following way:

```
    date        year
0   1994-12-15  1995
1   1995-07-06  1996
2   1995-09-13  1996
3   1995-12-12  1996
4   1996-03-14  1996
5   1996-07-01  1997
6   1996-09-17  1997
7   1996-11-12  1997
8   1996-12-13  1997
9   1997-06-25  1998
10  1997-09-10  1998
11  1997-12-12  1998
```

Please let me know if you have any idea of how I can go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with helper `DataFrame` created by minimal and maximal years and [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), it back filling value before cut-off by column `df1['year']`:

```
y = df['date'].dt.year
#added +-1 year (not necessary)
miny = y.min() - 1
maxy = y.max() + 2

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(f'{miny}-03-31', f'{maxy}-03-31', freq='A-Mar')})
df1['year'] = df1['date'].dt.year  + 1
print (df1)
        date  year
0 1993-03-31  1994
1 1994-03-31  1995
2 1995-03-31  1996
3 1996-03-31  1997
4 1997-03-31  1998
5 1998-03-31  1999
6 1999-03-31  2000

df = pd.merge_asof(df,df1,on='date')
print (df)
         date  year
0  1994-12-15  1995
1  1995-07-06  1996
2  1995-09-13  1996
3  1995-12-12  1996
4  1996-03-14  1996
5  1996-07-01  1997
6  1996-09-17  1997
7  1996-12-12  1997
8  1996-12-13  1997
9  1997-06-25  1998
10 1997-09-10  1998
11 1997-12-12  1998
```